# willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation is or is not called on various devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod

I have a problem with (I suppose) orientation callbacks.
My app runs in Landscape mode, but two modes are available (left/right).
In view controller I have three methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);
}
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // some setup
}
```

Then I get touches from callback and transform them to my coordinate system.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //...
    CGPoint     p=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:nil];
    // some transforms
}
```

And this works fine on all my test devices (iPhone 3GS - iOS6 and iPad2 iOS7) in all the cases. But, after the release in the App Store, I have two reports that after the screen rotation, touches do not work properly (iPad 4 and iPod 4 with iOS6). I may assume that method willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: is not being called, but I am a little confused on the origin of the behavior (as works for other devices with similar system). Have you seen a similar problem?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with iOS6, `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` method is no longer called for invisible view controllers. So if your view controller presents another which takes over, only the other one will hear these notifications.

It is best to move interface orientation logic into `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and query the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` property.

Comment: Thank you. Yes your answer was correct but the real problem was in much different place. The behavior was similar. The touch coordinates were badly transformed due to usage of screen resolution in pixels but not in the dots. And in one orientation there were negative :)